# How to create a UIButton and set frame using CGRect?

Tags: swift

hello I would like to ask a question, but if in object c to create a button with a given position (eg)

```
   # define kWidthButton 120 
   # define kHeightButton 80 

   - (UIButton*)createButtonWithIndex:(int)index{
   int row = index / 2; 
   int column = index %2; 
   UIButton * newButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
   newButton.frame = CGRectMake (* kWidthButton column, row * kHeightButton, kWidthButton, kHeightButton); 
   }
```

how can I make swift ?

I found to create a button that you can do it this way but for that value index in swift

```
let button   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 50)
```

Comment: All you're missing is passing it the values for width/height (like the objective c version) instead of `100, 100, 100, 50`

Comment: i solved in this mode :button.frame = CGRect(x:variable1, y:variable2, width:variable3, height:variable4)

Comment: could you put this in as an answer? Otherwise the question is still showing as open